# Uncopyable 5GB file, BTRFS

Tags: large-files, btrfs

I have a 5.3GB tar file, located on a BTRFS partitioned eSATA drive.  When trying to copy the file to another disk, or expand the tar the process seems to freeze.  No errors are generated, and waiting doesn't seem to bear any fruit.

When booted from this eSATA (64bit OS) I manage to copy no more than 12MB of the file, and when booted from another drive(32bit OS) I copy 361.4MB ( before freezing).

Comment: Do any errors appear in the system logs (`/var/log/kern.log` or wherever your unix variant puts the kernel logs)? What unix variant is this anyway, what implementation of `tar` (and which versions)? Did you do a RAM test recently?

Comment: Turns out it was the external case dying.  

Don't buy Fujicom.

Answer (score 1):

Which distro are you using? BTRFS is still pretty recent, so it helps to have a recent implementation of it.

Could this be a disk problem? Does the disk make any unusual noises? Could it be a computer problem? Does the computer you're using hang at other occations as well? What does **dmesg** say?

Try using **ionice** when copying the file over, to lower the io speed. It might help.

Also, trying a [different io scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009577/selecting-a-linux-i-o-scheduler) may be worth investigating.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the data is being copied too quickly. You could use a program like [`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) to both view the progress of the stream and set a rate limit. Not much, I know, but at least it'll let you do some trial and error.

Comment: Too quickly for what?

Comment: @not-a-user Too quickly for the onboard buffers to keep up? Too quickly for the heat sinks to leech off the heat generated from it? There are a lot of ways a drive can fail.

Answer (score 0):

BTRFS is still an experimental filesystem expected to have bugs.  You should report the bug on the [mailing list](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#linux-btrfs).